# Why does total size of dataset in neural network affect memory usage

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, out-of-memory, image-classification

Initially, I was trying transfer learning in image classification model using 268 test images + 65 validation images of 256x256 sizes.

(The code I am using is from https://github.com/conan7882/GoogLeNet-Inception)

However even with Tesla K80(16 gb memory), I still can't train more than batch size of 5.

Now that I increased the size of dataset to 480 test images + 120 validation images, the out of memory error pops up again. I have to reduce the batch size to 2 to continue training.

Why does dataset size matter in memory usage? Shouldn't only batch size decides how much data is being processed by the GPU?

Comment: What is the batch size for the first dataset?

Comment: @OmG It is 5. Can't train more than 5 with the first dataset otherwise OOM error happens.